# How to use AJAX to perform a MYSQLI query (prepared statement)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

So I have this (prepared statement) mysqli query in PHP (partial code):

```
#New DB connection
@ $mysqli = new mysqli ('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'database');

#Check DB connection, print error upon failure
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("<p>Connect failed.</p> <p>Error: \"%s\"</p>\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
} #if

#Check if userName already exists
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userName = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $registerUserName);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$num_results = $stmt->num_rows;
if ($num_results) {
    echo "<p>This user already exists. Please click your back button.</p>";
    exit;
}; #if
```

And I would like to execute this through Javascript/AJAX on an onblur event:

```
function checkForUser(str) {
  var xmlhttp;    
  if (str=="") {
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open(???,true); // not sure what goes here or if I should even use this method
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

So is this possible? and how? I found some tutorials but they involve using jquery. Can I do it without jquery?

Comment: What is the name of the file in question (where is the request supposed to go to)? Also where does `$registerUserName` get the value from?

Comment: Just do a simple google search for "ajax tutorial", replace the callback url to your php script posting the username you need and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed a little bit your code. Hope it will helpfull:

```
#New DB connection
@ $mysqli = new mysqli ('localhost', '…', '…', '…');

#Check DB connection, print error upon failure
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("<p>Connect failed.</p> <p>Error: \"%s\"</p>\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
} #if

#Check if userName already exists
$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE user_login = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_GET[registerUserName]); 
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$num_results = $stmt->num_rows;
if ($num_results) {
    echo "<p>This user already exists. Please click your back button.</p>";
    exit;
}; #if
```

Now we can call it with URL like   "/ttt.php?registerUserName=user1"
And function:

```
function checkForUser(uname)
{
var req;
req = null;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    try {
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){}
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    try {
        req = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
    } catch (e){
        try {
            req = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        } catch (e){}
    }
}

if (req) {       
    req.open("GET", "/ttt.php?registerUserName="+encodeURIComponent(uname), false);
    //req.onreadystatechange = processReqChange;
    req.send(null);
    if(req.status == 200) {
      return req.responseText;
    }

}
return false;
}
```

in the

```
req.open("GET", "/ttt.php?registerUserName="+encodeURIComponent(uname), false);
```

**false** means async request and  **req.send**  will wait for response from php script.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Much gratitude. I have not had a moment to try it out yet.. will get back to this post.

Comment: Not sure if you will see this.. Hi again, thanks for improved try/catch on older Explorer browsers.. Was wondering how you did away with 'req.onreadystatechange=function(){..'. I think you meant 'false' means 'synchronous' request, yes? 'true' is asynchronous and requires an onreadystatechange event(?)

Comment: Yes, right. `req.open(…,false)` shold wait for response. By default this parameter is `true` and executed asyncronously. If it is executed asyncronosly than another thread will call `onreadychange` event. But `checkForUser` function will be already finished by that time and cannot return any result.

Comment: But this can work asynchronously w/ onreadychange, no? Also how does it work synchronously as you coded? After 'req.send(null);' the function has to complete executing, correct? It's not like the function stops and waits until 'if(req.status == 200)' is fulfilled..

Comment: From w3schools: "Using async=false.. Remember that the JavaScript will NOT continue to execute, until the server response is ready. If the server is busy or slow, the application will hang or stop." I am wondering - how can a method stop Javascript code from executing? How can anything stop Javascript code from executing?

Comment: Of course you may call it asyncronously, but in this case function `checkForUser` never could return the result. It can only initiate this process. Result will be received and processed in `onreadychange` handler.

Comment: Ok, was wondering why you chose not to use asynchronous and 'onreadychange'? Anyway I finally got it to work, only difference, setting asynchronous to 'true', using 'POST' and onreadychange. Thanks for your help.