# PHP to show div info based on selected option in form

Tags: php, html

I want to use PHP to change a div's information based on what option is selected. Below is my HTML & PHP. I don't think I'm using the right operator or syntax in the if statement. I basically want to pull information from a table in my database based on the option selected. Right now I do not have that in my code because it is irrelevant at this point. Any help is appreciated.

```
    <select id=\"numberofstaff\">
        <option class=\"staffselection\" value=\"\">--Select--</option>
        <option class=\"staffselection\" value=\"smalljobsite\">1-3 staff</option>
        <option class=\"staffselection\" value=\"mediumjobsite\">4-7 staff</option>
        <option class=\"staffselection\" value=\"largejobsite\">8+ staff</option>
    </select>

<?php
$selectOption = $_POST['numberofstaff'];

echo "<div id='jobsite_price'><p>";
if ($selectOption == 'smalljobsite'){
    echo "smalljobsite";
};
if ($selectOption == 'mediumjobsite'){
    echo "mediumjobsite";
};
if ($selectOption == 'largejobsite'){
    echo "largejobsite";
};
echo "</p></div>";
    ?>
```

Comment: if you're using JS/Ajax for this, show it. Otherwise, you're missing important parts, such as form tags and a post method and naming the `<select>`. Your question is unclear.

Comment: Why don't use  `jQuery`?

Comment: I'm not using JS or AJAX. I didn't want to bombard my post with useless information and I thought this is all that would be needed. I just want to echo out some informatio based on what is selected. I thought I would be able to use PHP for this no?

Comment: *"I basically want to set something up as a previewer"* - To "preview" something, you need JS/Ajax for this.

Comment: @Lenap because I'm going to being using PHP to call table information within my echo statement but wanted to start with a simple example first.

Comment: @Fred -ii- fixed the syntax error. I was echoing out the select tag with php in my file and that's why there was a closing php tag and the " at the end. ty

Comment: @Fred -ii- Sorry I didn't explain myself better. I'm not using it as a previewer as much as I'll be using it to pull information from a table in my database but wanted to start with something simple for the time. If I can't get this to work, then there wouldn't be a point in trying to implement mysql.

Comment: I posted an answer for you below. Let me know if that's what you're looking for. Otherwise, see the other answer given.

Comment: @James If you're not using AJAX it wont work

Comment: so, where are we at here? did you see any of the answers given below? I posted an answer 15 mins. prior to this comment. Just run your SQL inside where I wrote `// RUN SQL HERE` in commented code.

Comment: @James I've made a few edits to my answer, in regards to running SQL statements. Reload it to see those changes, where I've explained a few things. You may have seen my original answer and trying to make your queries work, and are probably not succeeding. Let me know where you're at here and I'll be glad to help. Not hearing from you, doesn't expedite the process, it actually slows it down. I'm not the type of guy to leave people high and dry, but you really need to work with me here ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need form tags and a POST method, while giving the select a name attribute. You can't rely on an `id` alone, not without JS/Ajax anyway.

Sidenote: I removed the `\` from the escaped quotes, since they're not in an echo statement/PHP in your posted code. This would throw an error/warning such as "unquoted attribute". If you are using it inside an echo'd statement, then you'll need to add those back in.

- FYI: Escaping quotes `\"` is only done when inside an echo/PHP.

Additional note:

- If you want to run seperate SQL statements, it's rather simple. Where the echos are and where I have in a comment form `// RUN SQL HERE`, you can simply include a file in there with your SQL query. I do it myself and it cuts down on a lot of code and is more manageable that way.

HTML/PHP:

```
<form method="post" action="">

    <select id="numberofstaff" name="numberofstaff">
        <option class="staffselection" value="">--Select--</option>
        <option class="staffselection" value="smalljobsite">1-3 staff</option>
        <option class="staffselection" value="mediumjobsite">4-7 staff</option>
        <option class="staffselection" value="largejobsite">8+ staff</option>
    </select>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$selectOption = $_POST['numberofstaff'];

echo "<div id='jobsite_price'><p>";
if ($selectOption == 'smalljobsite'){

  // RUN SQL HERE

    echo "smalljobsite";
}
if ($selectOption == 'mediumjobsite'){

  // RUN SQL HERE

    echo "mediumjobsite";
}
if ($selectOption == 'largejobsite'){

  // RUN SQL HERE

    echo "largejobsite";
}
echo "</p></div>";

} // brace for if(isset($_POST['submit']))
?>
```

---

**Foonotes:**

To include files, you can use [`include()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

```
// Include your SQL query
include('query_file.php');
```

where you see `// RUN SQL HERE` in commented code.

Another option is to use Ajax.

Here are a few links:

- http://www.w3resource.com/ajax/working-with-PHP-and-MySQL.php
- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_and_ajax.htm
- [How to use AJAX to perform a MYSQLI query (prepared statement)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23376536/)

Comment: Sorry I haven't been able to look at my post yesterday at all. Got caught up with other things. This seems to be more of what I'm after. I realize probably AJAX and XML even may be the route to go but I'm even more unfamiliar with those than PHP. Thanks for your help! I'm going to give this a try later today and I'll let you know.

Comment: @James No worries, and you're very much welcome James, I was glad to help. Theoretically, this will/should work and as I mentioned in my answer, I use the "include" method in a lot of my code which makes it a lot more manageable, rather than having a lot of added code inside the same file.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just using php to check the selected value, you can use jquery for that, i.e.:

```js
$("select").on('change', function() {
  $("#jobsite_price").html("<p>"+$(this).val()+"</p>")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="numberofstaff">
        <option class="staffselection" value="">--Select--</option>
        <option class="staffselection" value="smalljobsite">1-3 staff</option>
        <option class="staffselection" value="mediumjobsite">4-7 staff</option>
        <option class="staffselection" value="largejobsite">8+ staff</option>
    </select>
<div id='jobsite_price'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pure javascript to do this.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){

    var el = document.querySelector("#numberofstaff");

    el.addEventListener('change', function(){

        var data = { numberofstaff : el.value };   

        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('POST', 'YourUrl.php', true);
        request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
        request.send(data); 

        request.onload = function(result){          
          document.querySelector("#jobsite_price").innerHTML = result.responseText;
        }   

    });    

});
```